# Como importar fontes locais pelo Vue/Vue-cli?

Tags: css, vue.js, css-font-face

Preciso importar uma fonte local para meu projeto em `Vue`, e não estou obtendo sucesso. Tentei utilizando o `@font-face`, dessa maneira:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    src: url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('../fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Coloquei sem o `url`, importei em um arquivo `styles`, e direto no componente `App`, tentei também colocando o `font-face` direto no componente que iria utilizar a fonte, e não deu certo. Alguém saberia me dizer a forma correta de importar fontes locais usando o `Vue` via `cli`?

Comment: deu certo a resposta?

Comment: não deu, porque pra importar a fonte no @font-face, não estava funcionando. respondi abaixo como eu consegui

Comment: Olha a minha resposta foi testada no Vuejs e funcionou! não tem nada a ver com o que você disse na sua resposta!

Comment: voce tá usando o vue-cli? por que o meu só funcionou assim, e estou usando o vue pelo vue-cli. a sua resposta não funcionou.. tem esse link aqui explicando isso tbm https://qastack.com.br/programming/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack

Comment: sim é pelo vue-cli, funciona sim ... se está enganada, do jeito que você fez é o tradicional, mas, do outro jeito funciona.

Comment: entendo, mas no projeto aqui não funcionou com dessa forma, só usando o @ mesmo para os caminhos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está configurado as suas pastas? Você colocou as fontes dentro da pasta `src`?

São perguntas a serem feitas, então para configurar um fonte local siga o seguintes passos:

Crie uma pasta dentro da pasta `src` com o nome de `fonts` (`src/fonts`) e coloque os arquivos dessa fonte dentro dessa pasta.

Crie um arquivo `app.scss` dentro da pasta `src` com o código igual ao seu mas, com um pequena diferença em vez de dois pontos um ponto como está no código:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    src: url('./fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('./fonts/Oxygen-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Para utilizar precisa agora importar para dentro da `tag` `style` do seu componente

```
<style>
    @import './app.scss';
</style>
```

[Um outra forma no site SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516084/how-do-i-add-a-google-font-to-a-vuejs-component)<sup>En</sup>

Comment: então, eu fiz uma pasta fonts dentro da minha pasta assets, localizada no src. e lá coloquei as fontes locais sim... apenas nao havia feito um arquivo para as fontes. vou testar dessa forma

Comment: então é `./assets/fonts` entendeu ...

Answer (score 0):

Como consegui resolver:

1. importando a fonte em um arquivo .scss através do @font-face, usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('OpenSans-Regular-400'), url(~@/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-400.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Descobri que no Vue usa-se a sintaxe **~@/pasta** para escrever os caminhos dos arquivos.